# при нажатии кнопки не переходит на новое окно а завершает приложение с ошибкой

Tags: java, android, activity

При нажатии кнопки не переходит на новое окно а завершает приложение с ошибкой

```
button_setting = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_setting);
button_setting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity_setting.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Манифест:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Activity_setting"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_setting"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
    //
    //  android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
    // android:value="ru.life.sendremedylite.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

> 10-12 11:09:05.937 2041-2041/ru.life.sendremedylite E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                         java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ru.life.sendremedylite.Activity_setting.getActionBar
>                                                                             at ru.life.sendremedylite.Activity_setting.onCreate(Activity_setting.java:15)
>                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

```
package ru.life.sendremedylite;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;

    public class Activity_setting extends Activity {

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

}

Comment: Будьте добры, опишите ошибку тоже, чтобы мы тут не гадали. Что за исключение, лог, вот это все.

Comment: в андроид студио ошибок не выдает, выдает ошибку при тестировании на самом телефоне

Comment: На 6 оси падает?

Comment: я делаю на 2.3.3 на телефоне на котором тестирую 5.02

Comment: может проблемма в API

Comment: в эмуляторе пишет has stopped unexpectedly

Comment: в logcat всегда есть stacktrace ошибки. Покажите его.

Comment: добавил в шапку вроде это

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код `Activity_setting`.

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `getActionBar()` на `getSupportActionBar()` и `extends Activity` на `extends AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: Попробуйте заменить getActionBar() на getSupportActionBar() и extends Activity на extends AppCompatActivity. – post_zeew ПОМОГЛО спасибо

Comment: спасибо, только так и не понял что я не так делал,где можно об этом почитать?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исключение `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` дословно говорит о том, что «*такой метод не найден*» и генерируется в тех случаях, когда не получается найти метод, который Вы вызываете.

Использование `ActionBar` на низких API возможно (*в частности*) с помощью библиотеки `AppCompat` и ее класса `AppCompatActivity` (в котором вместо метода `getActionBar()` определен метод `getSupportActionBar()` с аналогичным назначением).

Для решения данной проблемы, можете наследовать Вашу `Activity_setting` от `AppCompatActivity`:

```
public class Activity_setting extends AppCompatActivity {
...
}
```

и заменить метод `getActionBar()` на `getSupportActionBar()`.

Answer (score 0):

Стоит проверить в этом месте кода Activity_setting:

```
ru.life.sendremedylite.Activity_setting.onCreate(Activity_setting.java:15)
```

Также попробуйте увеличить значения Compile SDK version и Target SDK version в build.gradle до 21 или выше

Comment: мне нужно на api 10